# How can i read json key-value using inline script in git actions and pass them outside the bash tas a variable

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines, devops, cicd

How can i read json key-value using inline script in git actions and pass them outside the bash tas a variable, below is the file to create a resource group and parse the json from the repo and pass the vaues as variable to the parameter

```
  on: [push]
        name: sp_keyvault
        
        jobs:
          build-and-deploy:
            runs-on: ubuntu-latest
            env:
              ResourceGroupName: sp_keyvault-rg
              ResourceGroupLocation: "eastus"
            steps:
              - uses: actions/checkout@master
              - uses: azure/login@v1
                with:
                  creds: ${{ secrets.Azure_cred }}
              - uses: Azure/CLI@v1
                with:
                  inlineScript: |
                    #!/bin/bash
                    if $(az group exists --name ${{ env.ResourceGroupName }}) ; then
                      echo "Azure resource group already exists, skipping creation..."
                    else
                      az group create --name ${{ env.ResourceGroupName }} --location ${{ env.ResourceGroupLocation }}
                      echo "Azure resource group created"
                    fi

                    inlineScript: |
                    #!/bin/bash
                     #need to access json from the repo and pass it to parameter variable
              - uses: azure/arm-deploy@v1
                with:
                 resourceGroupName: ${{ env.ResourceGroupName }}
                 template: ./sp_repo-main/KeyVaultSetup.json
                 parameters: "need variable from bash script"
```

Comment: These are not *Git* actions, these are *GitHub* actions or Azure actions or some other CI actions. Each CI system has its own peculiarities and idiosyncrasies, so you'll need to identify which one you mean. I'm guessing azure here based on `az group` commands. If that's wrong, update the tags.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.